# Mysql read query is really slow. What is the problem in this situation?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `index_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `field2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `port` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `unq` (`ip`,`port`),
  KEY `idx` (`index_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6472004 DEFAULT
```

This is the table that the query is selecting. I run a program to insert rows in an infinite loop. Each loop runs an inserting query with 2000 rows for the table. Id is not provided in insert query, so it is auto increment. Ip and index_id(from 0 - 20000000) will be randomly generated. while the program is running, I run a query to select some rows, but the query is stuck at least 10+ seconds. Sometime it will be stuck forever.

```
select * from new_table where index_id > 2131223 limit 100;
```

They are the insert queries and a select query. Tablet is INNODB with RR isolation level, so it should not be a lock problem at all. I'm curious about what happen to the select query? If I try to sleep 1 second for each loop literation to slow down the insert query, the select query will be fine. Therefore I think the problem might be the priority between writing and reading?

Let me know if you have answer for this problem!

**Here is select query explain.**

```
mysql> explain select * from new_table where index_id > 2131223 limit 100;
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                            |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | new_table | NULL       | range | idx           | idx  | 4       | NULL | 2430541 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using MRR |
+----+-------------+-----------+------------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+----------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

---

**Update:**

The problem will be solved if I turn off MRR. I think the problem are between MRR and bulk insertions.

Comment: Can you run `EXPLAIN` on this query and include the output?  Note that using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` itself makes little sense.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I just post the explain. Yea, it's not a serious searching query. Because there are more than 30 million fake datas in the table, I have to use limit. Let me know if you have any ideas~` Thx:)

Comment: I can't explain the performance nuances you highlighted, but MySQL does seem to be using the index.  Also, it would have to scan the bulk of the index given the range expression you have in your query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think I might get the problem. The query has not  `ORDER BY`. By default it is using `ORDER BY ID ASC`. It will need to go through primary key to get 100 rows. That's why Mysql is using `MRR` to optimize the sorting. However if I turn off MRR, the select query will be executed for 0.03 seconds.